# ssh mysqldump to remote nas storage with cron storing command(s) in .sh file

Tags: linux, ssh, mysql

I'm trying to set up mysql database backups with cron in order to backup the mysql database to my local NAS storage. I would like to store the command(s) in the .sh file on the server and then use cron to execute it.

Up to now I've managed to get the command to save the database to my NAS (QNAP) from the remote server, which is:

```
mysqldump 
--add-drop-table 
--comments [database_name] 
-u [database_username] 
-p[database_password] | 
gzip -c | 
ssh [nas_user]@[nas_ip_address] 
    "cat > /share/mysqlBackup/backup-`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`.sql.gz"
```

The above works fine, but the problems I have are:

1. I'm not sure how to create the .sh file on the remote server and put
   the command in
2. This command asks for the password each time you
   execute it - is there a way to put it in the .sh file so that i can
   be executed in the background without prompting for it / or define
   the password in the command?

Examples of how to solve the above would be very welcome.

I believe that the **expect()** dialog could be used, but again - I'm not familiar with it and its documentation is a bit confusing for me.

Answer (score 2):

I guess password is asked for ssh connection, so you can make your ssh connection passwordless.

Here in the answer passwordless ssh connection is explained:
https://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password

After this step is done on your remote server rest is pretty straightforward you write the command you give above in an .sh file. And add it to cron to do this backing up periodically.

Comment: Thanks deniz, however I'm having difficulties with creating these rsa keys - when I type ssh-keygen I get 'NO such file or directory'. Any idea?

Comment: Ok - I got rid of the error. I've managed to generate keys and copy them to the NAS and it all works, but now it asks for the passphrase - because I've set one - otherwise it wouldn't really be that secure. So using the 'passwordless' option, as I've found out is not ideal. Any idea how to do it with the expect() dialog?